# Automatic DNS population for routable IPV6 addresses

Tags: ipv6

In ipv4 I can set my DHCP server to populate DNS with hostnames and IP addresses as clients are found. This works well and clients can resolve these DNS addresses to contact eachother over routed subnets. How can this be done in ipv6 without DHCP?

Link Local Multicast Name Resolution can allow clients on the same subnet to discover eachothers hostnames and match them to link-local addresses, but so far I can't find a way for clients to advertise their global or unique local addresses and hostnames to a DNS server to be resolved across subnets.

Comment: Are you not using DHCP for your IPv6 network?  Why wouldn't your DHCP server update the DNS zones also?

Comment: @Zoredache because DHCPv6 is only one of the two popular ways of assigning IP addresses to hosts in LANs under IPv6 and it is by far the heavier and less automatic of the two. The other one is [SLAAC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4862).

Comment: I don't really know what best practices around this are going to eventually fall out. Personally, I wrote a small utility (in C) for Linux which watches for changes in interface IP addresses and registers the current set in DNS using dynamic DNS (the real DDNS that is part of the DNS protocol, not the nonsense from DynDNS.org & co.). Each host is thus responsible for registering itself (and has a copy of the shared TSIG key to do it).

Comment: @Celada, perhaps I am missing something, but I didn't think SLAAC could deliver settings like the IPv6 address(s) of your DNS server(s).  I thought DHCP was pretty much required.  Either that or maybe some kind of Multicast DNS setup.

Comment: [SLAAC can in fact deliver IP addresses of DNS servers](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5006), but it is true that DHCPv6 is required for some of the fancier options like NTP server or netboot parameters. Still, those options can be delivered using *stateless* DHCP while still using SLAAC for the actual address assignment. That's advantageous because stateless DHCP is much more lightweight than stateful DHCP (which is required if using DHCP for address assignment).

Comment: OP and @Celada, long ago question now, but, what would the best practice for this be today? I.E. hostnames for IPv6:s on LAN, preferably using stateless DHCPv6 and SLAAC.